# Multiple boot and file sharing options

Tags: filesystems, macbook, operating-systems, multi-boot

I am about to set up a dual/triple boot system on a 750gig macbook pro and was wanting to know my options in regards to file sharing options between the operating systems--primarily to share my music library.

The macbook pro comes with OS X 10.7.4 (Lion), and I was wanting to put Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on the the HD. I mainly use Linux and Windows; I was only keeping the pre-installed OS X since I have 750gigs and I may find a use for it later. Also, bootcamp looks like it will make things easier with windows.

**My question:**

I have 150gig of music files that I want to share between the OS's. How should I organise the three OS's and the 150gig of files on the HD (and maybe some room for expansion or other smaller files? Should I create 4 partitions, one for each OS and one for the files and then connect them all somehow, or put the files on one of the OS's partition and then connect to them there? What are the benefits of each method and are there any other solutions for what I want to do?

Any advice on how to perform any suggested structures would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Windows cannot access data from other FORMAT drives apart from FAT32 , NTFS. So Having three different partitions for three OS will be logical.

If you want you can Either create a new NTFS  (Fourth) partition for your music files  so accessing them through all the OS will be easier,

Or keep them in Windows partition ,which is  equally accessible .

Having a Different ( NTFS) partition for Music Files will be recommended , since removal or changing of any OS will not affect them anyhow.

NOTE : You can autoMount the NTFS partition in LINUX/Ubuntu OS ,which saves the trouble of mounting it every time Whilst in Linux/Ubuntu OS. [ i don't know about mac , but installing Windows before Ubuntu is recommended]

Comment: If I create a 4th partition, since I am starting off in OS X, there doesn't seem to be an NTFS option in disk utility (only MS-DOS(FAT)), am I supposed to leave some blank space and then partition it as NTFS once I have Windows installed or something? or will MS-DOS(FAT) be ok?

Comment: The contents from NTFS will be readable by OS X, but it cannot write data in NTFS, due to licensing problems. You can refer [this](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57401784-285/the-best-ways-to-format-an-external-drive-for-windows-and-mac/) ( don't worry even if it says external drive) and select the best as requirements, and  MS-DOS(Fat) has its [limitations](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;184006).